# SWI-Prolog Association List Library doesn't appear to work

Tags: prolog, associative-array

I've been playing with the association list library `library(assoc)` that comes with SWI. However, the predicate `put_assoc/4` appears to simply not work. If I try the following query

```
?- empty_assoc(E), put_assoc("foo", F, "bar", E).
```

hangs indefinitely. I can't tell if there is some obvious mistake I am making here, because I can't see any reason why this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the order of the arguments in the call to the `put_assoc/4` predicate wrong. It should be:

```
?- empty_assoc(Empty), put_assoc("foo", Empty, "bar", Updated).
Empty = t,
Updated = t("foo", "bar", -, t, t).
```